# Group results by UserID then create array of column data

Tags: php, mysql, css

Currently using the following:

```
SELECT o.*, u.*
FROM Owned o
INNER JOIN Users u USING (UserID)
```

Users "own" divs, some may own more than others and I'd like to apply their User ID to a generated div. So for example User 123 may own div's 3b and 5c, so I'd like to do something like:

```
#3b,#5c {
    background: url($row['logo']);
}
```

Currently I have it doing the following:

```
#3b {
    background: url(<?=$row['logo']?>);
}
#5c {
    background: url(<?=$row['logo']?>);
}
```

Which means making a lot of unnecessary calls to the database. How would I best go about building an array of `$row['ownedID']` to do the following for each user:

```
foreach user {
    #<?=$ownedID[]?>{
        background: url(<?=$row['logo']?>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT UserId, GROUP_CONCAT(o.div) as divs
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     Owned o
     USING (UserID) 
GROUP BY UserId;
```

This concatenates the divs into a single string.

You can just add a character in front if you like:

```
SELECT UserId, GROUP_CONCAT('#', o.div) as divs
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     Owned o
     USING (UserID) 
GROUP BY UserId;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT()` concatenates its first arguments together without the need for an explicit `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Very very nearly! That outputs the results as `3b,5c,7g` etc is it possible without using preg_replace to make them `#3b,#5c,#7g` ?